# MongoDB find internal array

Tags: arrays, mongodb, filter

I'm new on MongoDB and I want to filter an internal array. The current document looks like:

```
{
    "data1": "value1",
    "data2": "value2",
    ...
    "array1": [
        {
            "field1": field1value"
            "field2": field2value"
        },
        {
            "field1": expectedvalue"
            "field2": field2value"
        },
    ]
}
```

And I expect a result like:

```
{
    "data1": "value1",
    "data2": "value2",
    ...
    "array1": [
        {
            "field1": expectedvalue"
            "field2": field2value"
        },
    ]
}
```

I tried find and also aggregate as suggested in [In MongoDB, how do I search in an array of sub-documents?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30525084/in-mongodb-how-do-i-search-in-an-array-of-sub-documents) and other similar question.

The problem is that I lose all the information outside the array (data1, data2, ...):

```
{
    "_id" : { "$oid" : "8001212651b8a68278edbc92"},
    "array1": [
        {
            "field1": expectedvalue"
            "field2": field2value"
        },
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To only return the subdocuments in the `array1` array which match a given condition you have to [project](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/) and [filter](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/) (available in versions >= 3.2). Here's an example:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    // this is optional, it is only included here to show you that you _can_ match 
    // the documents before you match the array of sub documents
    {$match: {data1: 'value1'}},
    {$project: {
            data1: 1,
            data2: 1,
            array1: {$filter: {
                input: '$array1',
                as: 'a',
                cond: {$eq: ['$$a.field1', 'expectedvalue']}
            }}
        }}
])
```

This will return the following:

```
{
    "_id" : ...,
    "data1" : "value1",
    "data2" : "value2",
    "array1" : [ 
        {
            "field1" : "expectedvalue",
            "field2" : "field2value"
        }
    ]
}
```

The answer you linked to relates to the Mongo Java Driver so in case you need to run this query via the Java driver, here it is:

```
    List<Document> documents = collection.aggregate(Arrays.asList(
            new Document("$project", new Document()
                    // include data1
                    .append("data1", 1)
                    // include data2
                    .append("data2", 1)
                    // include only those elements of array1 which match the filter condition
                    .append("array1", new Document("$filter",
                            new Document("input", "$array1")
                                    .append("as", "a")
                                    .append("cond", new Document("$eq", Arrays.asList("$$a.field1", "expectedvalue"))))))
    )).into(new ArrayList<>());
```

Comment: Just a question: Can I obtain in the result the values of data1, data2, ... without gettting/setting it's values explicitily in the resulting document?

Comment: In order to filter the array of sub documents you must use the `$project` operator and since you are using the `$project` operator you have to tell MongoDB what you want to project i.e. you have to explicitly include `data1`, `data2` etc by adding entries to the `$project` document like so: `attribute_name: 1`.

Comment: Ok, thank you so much. I thought I can do something like 'replace my old array with my newly filtered array' without the need of building all the original* document again

* the data outside the array as it remains the same.